# template inheritance and abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I have 2 problems with the following classes. I got 2 errors: the first probably is an issue about inheritance among template classes, the other about initializing an abstract class when this class in fact is not abstract (see comments in the code)

some_header.h

```
 template <typename T, typename R>
 class SDE  // abstract class
 {

     protected:
          T drift, diffusion;  // drift and diffusion terms
          T initialValue;
          Interval<R> range;


     public:
        virtual  T GetInitialValue() = 0;  // initial condition
        virtual  T GetDrift() = 0;
        virtual  T GetDiffusion() = 0;
        virtual  ~SDE();


};

#include "SDE.h"
#include <cmath>


 template <typename T, typename R>    // Cox, Ingersoll, Ross sde
 class CIRSDE : public SDE<T,R>
 {


  private:
       T kappa, theta, sigma;

  public:
        CIRSDE(const T& _initialValue,
               const Interval<R>& _range,
               const T& _kappa,
               const T& _theta,
               const T& _sigma);

        CIRSDE();
        ~CIRSDE(){};

        T GetInitialValue();
        T GetDrift(const T& t, const T& r);
        T GetDiffusion(const T& t, const T& r);

};


template <typename T, typename R>
CIRSDE<T,R> :: CIRSDE(const T& _initialValue,
                  const Interval<R>& _range,
                  const T& _kappa,
                  const T& _theta,
                  const T& _sigma)
{
   kappa = _kappa;
   theta = _theta;
   sigma = _sigma;
   SDE<T,R> :: initialValue = _initialValue;
   SDE<T,R> :: range = _range;
}

template <typename T, typename R>
CIRSDE<T,R> :: CIRSDE()
{
   kappa = 1;
   theta = 1;
   sigma = 1;
   SDE<T,R> :: initialValue = 1;
   SDE<T,R> :: range = Interval<R>(0,1);
}


template <typename T, typename R>
T CIRSDE<T,R> :: GetDrift (const T& t, const T& r)
{
     return kappa * (theta - r);
}

 template <typename T, typename R>
 T CIRSDE<T,R> ::  GetDiffusion(const T& t, const T& r)
 {
     return sigma * sqrt(r);
 }

 template <typename T, typename R>
 T CIRSDE<T,R> :: GetInitialValue()
 {
       return  initialValue;     // ERROR 1
       // undeclared identifier "initialValue"
 }
```

main.cpp

```
 #include "some_header.h"

 int main()
 {
     Interval<int> range(0,5);

     CIRSDE<int, int> a (1, range, 3,3,3); //ERROR2
     // variable CIRSDE<> is an abstract class

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The first error is a problem with dependent name lookup (base classes dependent on template parameters are not searched when using an unqualified name). Use `SDE<T,R> :: initialValue` just like in the constructor.

Comment: The second error is probably that you seem to try to override the virtual functions `GetDiffusion` and `GetInitialValue` in `CIRSDE`. Overriding virtual functions requires the using exact same parameter list and a covariant return type. I.e. you're not overriding those functions, but hiding the base class functions with *new, unrelated*  functions.

Comment: Next time, please provide a *complete* example. The class template `Interval` is missing here.

Comment: Hm. I tried to understand how you separated this into files, but it doesn't quite make sense to me. Feel free to fix this. Note that templates have to be defined in header files (unless you explicitly instantiate or specialize them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error 1:

```
 template <typename T, typename R>
 T CIRSDE<T,R> :: GetInitialValue()
 {
       return  initialValue;     // ERROR 1
       // undeclared identifier "initialValue"
 }
```

This is a problem with lookup. The identifier `initialValue` is not dependent on the template arguments and is thus resolved during the first pass before the actual types are substituted in and without checking in the base (the base is really not known until you substitute the types!)

You can solve it by qualifying as you did before `SDE<T,R>::initialValue` or by using `this`:

```
       return this->initialValue;
```

> Error 2

```
CIRSDE<int, int> a (1, range, 3,3,3); //ERROR2
// variable CIRSDE<> is an abstract class
```

The problem is that the base has a couple of pure virtual functions for which you did not provide a definition in `CIRSDE`. In particular:

```
    virtual  T GetDrift() = 0;
    virtual  T GetDiffusion() = 0;
```

Note that the following, in the derived type, are not override as their signatures don't match:

```
    T GetDrift(const T& t, const T& r);
    T GetDiffusion(const T& t, const T& r);
```